# Compute E(X|Y) when P(Y=2)=1

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I have a problem and don't understand a lot of stuff in there.

> First, it is given that if there are random variable X and Y where X has a well defined finite expectation, the, $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ is defined as the unique random variable that satisfies
>
> > a) $F_{\mathbb{E}(X|Y)} \subseteq F_{Y}$
> >     b) for any $A \in F_{Y}, \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{A}\mathbb{E}(X|Y)) = \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{I}_{A}X).$
>
> Then, the question is :
>
> > Let $\Omega =[0,1], F$ be the Borel $\sigma$-field in [0,1] and let $\mathbb{P}$ be the Lebesgue measurement. 
> > Let $X(\omega)=2\omega$ for all $\omega \in[0,1]$ and let $Y(\omega)=2$ for all $\omega \in [0,1]$.
> >
> > > i) Compute $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ 
> > > ii) Show that  $\mathbb{E}(X|Y)$ satisfies the two conditions above.

First, I don't understand the notation $\mathbb{I}_{A}$. 

Also, just in general, how to go about solving conditional expectation.

Comment: $\mathbb{I}_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$, i.e. the function which is $1$ when $\omega\in A$ and is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Condition b) says that $\int_A \mathbb{E}(X|Y)\ d\mathbb{P}=\int_A X \ d\mathbb{P}$ for all $A \in F_Y$. So $E(X|Y)$ is a random variable that is measurable with respect to $F_Y$ and has the same "average" as $X$ on all sets $A \in F_Y$. The first step to solving this problem should be to determine $F_Y$ for the $Y$ you are given.

Comment: Technically, conditional expectations are not unique, as they may vary on a set of probability zero.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a degenerate random variable is trivial. Because $\mathbb P(Y=2)=1$, we have $Y^{-1}(B)=\varnothing$ if $2\notin B$ and $Y^{-1}(B)=[0,1]$ if $2\in B$, and hence $$\sigma(Y) := \left\{Y^{-1}(B): B\in\mathcal B_{[0,1]} \right\}=\{\varnothing,[0,1]\}. $$
We compute $$\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{\varnothing}]=0 $$ and $$\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^1 2x\ \mathsf dx = 1. $$ It follows that $$\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=1.$$